# Graphics object not using correct font when drawing a string

Tags: c#

I'm creating a console app that will generate a image with text in it.
I'm using the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(400, 50);
Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
Font f = new Font("Arial", 12, FontStyle.Regular);
g.DrawString("My text", f, Brushes.Black, 10, 10);
```

But the result is always the following image, regardless of what font family i use instead of Arial.

[image]

Comment: `g.Clear(Color.White);` - Fill the graphics with some color.

Comment: After `bmp.Save("D:\\xtest.png");` and including `g.Clear(Color.White);` the result looks just fine and uses any font I put in. You don't seem to show the real code..Make sure that you draw the string only once! You may also test a few of the Grphics text properties..

Comment: The newly created bitmap has a transparent background. Because of this, anti-aliasing, smoothing, and similar functions do not work when displaying text.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `g.Clear(Color.White)` solved it for me. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newly created bitmap has a transparent background. Because of this, anti-aliasing, smoothing, and similar functions do not work when drawing text.

Fill the graphics with some color

```
g.Clear(Color.White);
```